# Django ImproperlyCongfigured Error for script

Tags: python, django, model

I would like to have one time insert script in django to the database configured in the settings.
This script could be rerun and would only insert once

i was going to have something like

```
my_list =[{key:value},{key:value}]
with transaction.atomic():
    for item in my_list:
         my_model = a_model(my_key=item['key'])
         my_model.save()
```

But I don't know how to get it running.  because it does not have the django context and gives me an error about improperly configured django

Comment: `python manage.py shell` will open a python shell with the django context which I guess is what you want? tbh im not really sure what you are asking...

Comment: yeah , This is what i want.  If you would like to answer the question, i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you write a `script.py` file

add the following

```
import sys,os
sys.path.append("/path/to/my_project")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MyDjangoModule.settings")
import django
django.setup()
#now django context is setup
```

another alternative is to create a manage.py admin command script to do this for you follow the directions in the django docs

eg

**my_django/management/commands/installx.py**

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from polls.models import Question as Poll

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'install some fixtures'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        # parser.add_argument('poll_id', nargs='+', type=int)
        pass # add arguments if you want

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        my_list =[{key:value},{key:value}]
        with transaction.atomic():
        for item in my_list:
              my_model = a_model(my_key=item['key'])
              my_model.save()
```

and then trigger it with

```
$ python manage.py installx
```

or you can simply open a shell with context for django

```
$ python manage.py shell
# loads up django context
>>> some_commands
```